# Building a Debian binary for Emacs 25.1: dpkg-source: control doesn't list any binary package

Tags: packaging, emacs

I have been trying to build a package for GNU Emacs 25.1 using the control file:

```
Package: emacs
Priority: extra
Section: checkinstall
Installed-Size: 129184
Maintainer: Brenton Horne <example@example.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 25.1-1
Provides: emacs
Description: GNU Emacs, the extensible and self-documenting text editor.
Source: gnu
Depends: gconf-service, libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-8), libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libc6 (>= 2.16), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.94), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgconf-2-4 (>= 3.2.5), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgif7 (>= 5.1), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3), libgnutls30 (>= 3.4.2), libgpm2 (>= 1.20.4), libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libm17n-0 (>= 1.6.1), libmagickcore-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2), libmagickwand-6.q16-2 (>= 8:6.8.8.2), libotf0 (>= 0.9.11), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.18.0), libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4), librsvg2-2 (>= 2.14.4), libselinux1 (>= 1.32), libsm6, libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3), libtinfo5 (>= 6), libx11-6, libxft2 (>> 2.1.1), libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libxpm4, libxrender1, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
Package-List: emacs
Binary-Package: emacs
```

as you may be able to guess this control file was originally created by Checkinstall. Unfortunately, running `dpkg-buildpackage` with this control file gives the error message:

```
dpkg-source: error: emacs/debian/control doesn't list any binary package
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried removing 'Binary-Package' section from the source?

Comment: Sure have, I only added that section **after** I first received this error. That is, it was part of my attempt to fix this problem.

Comment: also with removed Package-List section?

Comment: Yep, that was another section I added in an attempt to fix my problem.

Comment: There are many workflows  to build debian package. It is more convenient if you expend the question with more details: what your objectives? how did you get the source? how did you create debian folder or are you following specific instructions from somewhere ? Are you building a debian *binary* package or a debian *source* package?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the debian/control file needs a `Source:` section.  See the [debian-policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) section 5.2.
Also, make sure that the source name in the debian/changelog matches the source and binary names.  If e.g. the top entry of the changelog looks like

```
emacs25 (25.1-private) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium
```

then you should use `emacs25` after `Source:` and `Package:` (assuming you only want *one binary package* called `emacs25`).

I might be wrong, these are just things I would expect, judging from experience.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
$ apt-get source emacs24
```

Study how it was done there.

Run

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24
```

To get pkgs that will be needed.

Then copy the debian directory into new source, and start revising the control and rules files. It is vital to run

```
$ dch
```

Because that file specifies version number.

To build, I urge

```
$ dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
```

When you are adapting debian directory, many parts will not need fixing. If there is trouble, consider setting the patches subfolder out of the way. Those patches may not be relevant anymore.

I think that is a good learning experience! But if you just want Emacs packages, use Emacs 25 from a ppa

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/prebuilt-ubuntu-emacs-25-1

You can even get their source and study their work in debian folder :)

More web sources for packages:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSnapshotAndDebian

Comment: I've done those apt commands, there should be a `sudo` before the build-dep command as `$` indicates a non-root console. Plus you should use the package `emacs24` instead of `emacs` as the `emacs24` package is what actually provides emacs. The `emacs` package is more of a meta-package and running `sudo apt-get build-deps emacs` will install `emacs24` which is **not** wanted, as it will conflict with any build of emacs I make and try to install. I don't use the Ubuntu developer's technique of building Emacs packages because they split it up into several sub-packages, which is not what I want.

Comment: Thanks @Breton Home. I corrected emacs -> emacs24, inserted a sudo.